# Evaluate $(x^{1/3}+1)/(x+1)$ as $x$ approaches to $-1$.

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate the limit
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-1} {x^{1/3} + 1\over x+1}$ ?

Comment: Please format your question better, e.g. by using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please show some effort, we can't help unless you write down your workings. If you're struggling with Mathjax, see here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're looking for
$$\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} + 1}{x+1}$$
You can recognize a derivative in this (see @ILoveMath's answer), you could use l'Hôpital's rule or notice that according to $\color{blue}{a^3+b^3}=\color{red}{(a+b)}\color{purple}{(a^2-ab+b^2)}$, you can factor the denominator:
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x} + 1}{\color{blue}{x+1}} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} + 1}{\color{red}{(\sqrt[3]{x} + 1)}\color{purple}{(\cdots)}} = \frac{\cancel{\sqrt[3]{x} + 1}}{\cancel{\color{red}{(\sqrt[3]{x} + 1)}}\color{purple}{(\cdots)}} = \frac{1}{\color{purple}{\cdots}}$$
So:
$$\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} + 1}{x+1} = \lim_{x\to-1} \frac{1}{\color{purple}{\cdots}}$$
Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

## HINT:

Let $f(x) = x^{1/3}$, then

$$ \frac{ d }{dx} f(x) \bigg\rvert_{x=-1} = \lim_{x\to -1} \frac{ f(x) - f(-1) }{x + 1 } $$

Comment: sorry sir @ilovemath i didn't get it  !

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that for $x\not=-1$,
$${x^{1/3} + 1\over x+1}=\frac{1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sqrt[3]x+1=y\implies x=(y-1)^3$$

$$x+1=y(y^2-3y+3)$$

Now use the fact $x\to-1,y\to0\implies y\ne0$